# Can't login after installing LXQt on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, lxqt

I am using Lubuntu 14.04. I read about LXQt, the next generation lightweight desktop environment, so I decided to try it. I added [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/+archive/lubuntu-daily) and then did apt-get update/upgrade and installed the *lxqt-metapackage* package.

Now when I try to login to LXQt desktop it just logs out instantly. I can login to the default Lubuntu desktop as usual.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: That's the thing with daily builds, one day can work and the next day they can't.

Comment: @xangua Have you tried lxqt ? Did it work ?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gilir/q-project
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxqt-metapackage lxqt-panel openbox
```

Or you can read tutorial here: http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/05/how-to-install-lxqt-0-7-0-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr.html (include video)